# Changing substring from our to or

Tags: string, replace, char, substring

I'm currently trying to change a Canadian sentence like "The colour of our neighbours flag" to "The color of our neighbors flag"
The code needs to remove the 'u' in our to change it to or (the easy part)
But it also has to check to see if the char in front of the sub-string "our" is a space and if it is then it will leave it as "our".

Comment: "hor", "dor", "scor", "tor", "for" . . . Your rules are not robust enough.  You should keep a dictionary with the substitutions you want and use that.  Not to mention "colours", "honoured", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need something either much more complex than your defined rule ("space in front of 'our'") or you are going to need to use a list of words that should be fixed.  Consider the name "Doug".  I don't think he'd like being called Dog, even if he were an American...

You should consider lookup table of words that need to be changed, I suppose.

Wikipedia has a [list of spelling variants between U.S. and U.K. English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_spelling_variants).

Were you to build that list into something in your code, you could then attack it with regex patterns.  You could loop through the list and do a global search/replace (accounting for letter case, of course), or you could simply use regex to find any word with 'ou' in it and then check the entire word against some sort of hashmap to pull in a replacement if one exists.

The regex `(\b\w*ou\w*\b)` would find words that contain ou that you could then lookup against that hashmap.

Hope that helps.